# inputing data into a specific sections row

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I want to input only into the first row of a section. How would this be achieved?

I haven't been able to do this however this is what makes the most sense to me in terms of programming it.

```
if indexPath.section == 1 {
    let text = tableView.cellForRow(at:0) 
    text.categoryLabel.text! = "text goes here"

}
```

Comment: You might want to include row condition as `if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {`

Answer (score 0):

You should first add the text into the array you are using to load the tableView with:

```
//Add text input into Array
self.array.insert("The Text Message", at: 0)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
//Insert into TableView
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Let me know if this helps you.